# Trying to find the previous six days given any date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I'm using strtotime just fine for finding the previous week and next week's entries in my database, but what I can't seem to find is how to find the previous six days if the user selects a past date.

Here's how I know what today and six days previous are:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$minus6 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-6 days'));
```

Now how can I switch $today with $dateString as provided by my users' input?
I thought something like this based on my google searches, but it yields no results:

```
$dateString = 2010-01-25; // for example
$minus6 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-6 days, $dateString');
```

Am I missing some fundamental information regarding dates, strtotime, or what?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the actual date before any of the modifiers to strtotime(). For example:

```
$dateString = 2010-01-25; // for example
$minus6 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-6 days, $dateString'));
```

Should become:-

```
$dateString = "2010-01-25"; // for example
$minus6 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$dateString -6 days"));
```

...or pass it in as an explicit timestamp as a second parameter to strtotime() as per Gordon's answer.

Comment: +1. didn't know you can do the datestring and the modifier in one go. Changed your single quotes to double quotes though, because with single quotes $datestring wont be evaluated.

Comment: Right enough, I'm not sure if there a proper preferred method myself. Cheers for spotting the quotes.

Comment: Okay, that did it.  The double quotes makes it work.  However I think what was tripping me up was the comma between '$dateString, -6 days'.

Answer (score 3):

The second param to [`strtotime`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is a timestamp from which the first argument will be calculated:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-6 days', strtotime($dateString));
```

But you can also do it [like Gavin suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519316/trying-to-find-the-previous-six-days-given-any-date/2519348#2519348).